# Как правильно организовать несколько параллельных python процессов?

Tags: python, sqlite, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Рассмотрим кейс:

Есть БД с параметрами, которые передаются питоновскому скрипту.

Питоновский скрипт, который на вход принимает параметр из БД, и возвращает другие параметры, которые записываются в эту же БД, отработанный параметр помечается.

Задача: Запустить несколько питоновских скриптов, при этом чтобы не было конфликтов чтения\записи и помеченные параметры не отрабатывались заново.

БД - sqlite, то есть во время записи она locked.

Comment: Сделайте лучше одно псевдомногопоточное (multithreading) приложение, в скорости потеряете, но избавитесь от кучи ненужной головной боли с пайпами или подключением mq. После этого на уровне какого-нибудь striped lock блокируйте ресурсы.

Comment: Правильно будет не использовать SQLite при работе с несколькими параллельными процессами. Для задачи (распределённая очередь задач) необходим брокер, например на основе Mongo DB, Redis, или RabbitMQ. Посмотрите к примеру как [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) реализована.

Answer (score 1):

Для подобной задачи можно использоваться [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) и не использовать sqlite.

Celery более или менее хорошо реализует многопоточную обработку задач. Ставить их можно либо по расписанию с помощью [Celery beat](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html?highlight=periodic%20task#periodic-tasks), либо скриптом. Есть возможность организовать повторные попытки записи, если БД была занята.

У Celery так же неплохо описаны [первые шаги](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).

Из минусов:

- Не всегда самая стабильная работа (воркеры иногда отваливаются и их приходится перезапускать)
- В качестве брокера используйте только RabitMQ или Redis (если проблемы возникнут с другими брокерами, поддержки от контрибьюторов не дождетесь)
- Местами ужасный код

И все-таки это решение лучше, чем реализовывать многопоточность или мультитредовость самостоятельно.